# [crystal] Is there a limit on the array.resize?

Tags: ros, ros2, array, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to resize a embedded array only 128 values are printed.
After the 128 values, a  `'...']` is shown.
This is when using ros2 topic echo.

Is this to be expected?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315337/%5Bcrystal%5D-is-there-a-limit-on-the-array.resize?/) by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2019-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is this to be expected?

Yes, and it is also not a limit to array/list/sequence sizes in the message format (as your question seems to imply), but a usability feature.

The ROS 2 `rostopic` CLI tool by default will not print full length arrays for lists/arrays/sequences longer than [`128` elements](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/blob/2f9e81d86b06e1b5f397bdfdbd33493cbc5f27c1/ros2topic/ros2topic/verb/echo.py#L30) to prevent "runaway" terminals (where you are waiting 5 minutes for `rostopic` to quit after having `rostopic echo`d a topic carrying `PointCloud` msgs fi).

You can disable/change this behaviour in two ways:

1. provide an alternative value with the `--truncate-length` option ([here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/blob/2f9e81d86b06e1b5f397bdfdbd33493cbc5f27c1/ros2topic/ros2topic/verb/echo.py#L64-L67))
2. add `--full-length` to your `echo` invocation ([here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/blob/2f9e81d86b06e1b5f397bdfdbd33493cbc5f27c1/ros2topic/ros2topic/verb/echo.py#L59-L63))

Note that this is similar to `rostopic echo`'s `--noarr` in ROS 1 (although that didn't allow you to specify a limit to the nr of elements it did print).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-02-13**:
Thank you for the information, I will try the above mentioned changes.

I was hopping to ask another question relating topic echo.
Embedded custom messages are not being printed with ROS2 topic echo but,
if I create a subscriber, the messages are properly being received.  Is this a setting issue?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-14**:
That would seem to be a different question. Posting follow-up questions in comments on answered questions is not a good idea, as they have very limited visibility and will be hard to find for future readers.

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-02-14**:
Yea, sorry about that. I was just thinking that it might be related the rostopic echo setting as well. That is why I was debating whether to ask a different question or post it here.
Thank you for your answer though.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-14**:
No problem.